# java arraylist not working in for loop

Tags: java, android, arraylist

am new to java and facing problem with arraylist , i do not know whats wrong with my "for loop" am unable to exit it , producing error it end

```
        ArrayList<String> r2 = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0; i<= idx.length; i++) {
            ArrayList<String> r = db.Fetch(idx[i],exta); 
            if(r.size() != 0) {  
                for (String s : r) {
                    r2.add(s);
                    Log.d("test","ID "+idx[i]+ " :" + s);
                }
            }
        }
```

When i run it i get correct values printed on Log.d but the loop not exit it end
so help

Comment: What is `idx`? Also, the inner `for`-loop seems to be correct.

Comment: can you post your complete code? to be clearer

Comment: Your error is in the 2nd line. Try following code `for(int i=0; i<idx.length; i++)`. Since the for-loop starts at 0, you can't access an element at location X if the size of the ArrayList. The way your code is build up right now, you'll run into an ArrayOutOfBoundsException...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(int i=0; i<= idx.length; i++)
```

the indexes of you ArrayList go from `0` to `idx.lenght -1` . Looping on the `idx.lenght` index will cause an `ArrayIndexOutBoundExeception`. Change it in

```
   for(int i=0; i <  idx.length; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<String> r2 = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0; i< idx.length; i++)
{
    ArrayList<String> r = db.Fetch(idx[i],exta); 

    if(r.size() != 0) {  
        for (String s : r)
        {
            r2.add(s);
            Log.d("test","ID "+idx[i]+ " :" + s);
        }
    }
}
```

This should work now.  You start i at 0 so when i will be equal to idx.length your array at this position dos not exist.